# Создание словаря на python

Tags: python, dict

Есть код,

```
a='a'
b='b'
print(dict(a=a, b=b))
# выводит {'a': 'a', 'b':'b'}
```

так вот хотелось бы избежать вот этого повторения а=а, б=б.
Конечно, я мог бы и сам такую функцию написать, но всё таки хочется найти решение из стандартной библиотеки Python.

Comment: {x:x for x in [a,b]}

Comment: неплохо)
спасибо :3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lecron нашел подходящее решение:

```
{x:x for x in [a,b]}
```

Comment: У вас названия переменных всегда совпадают с их значениями, что ли?